Integral Surface passing through two curves
Find the integral surface of the quasi-linear equation
$$
\left(y - \phi\right)\frac{\partial \phi }{\partial x} + \left(\phi -x\right)\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y} = x - y
$$ which passes through the curve $\phi =0,\
 xy=1$ and through the circle
$$
\left\{\left(x,y\right) \mid x+y+\phi =0,\quad
x^{2}+y^{2}+\phi ^{2}=a^{2}\right\}
$$

I know how to find an integral Surface passing through one curve but I just can't think of any way to solve for two curves.

Is the question asking to calculate both the parts separately.
Kindly, help!!
Thanks and regards in advance.

What have you tried? It looks as if multiple components of the problem are set up to cancel out nicely

Is there a typo in the second condition : The integral surface which passes through the circle
$\left{\left(x,y\right) \mid x+y+\phi =0,\quad
x^{2}+y^{2}+\phi ^{2}=a^{2}\right}$ ? This is not a circle but an ellipse because $:x^2+y^2+\phi^2=a^2\quad\implies\quad x^2+y^2+(-x-y)^2=a^2 \quad\implies\quad x^2+y^2+xy=\frac{a^2}{2}$

The Lagrange-Charpit equations for the given PDE are
$$
\frac{dx}{y-\phi}=\frac{dy}{\phi-x}=\frac{d\phi}{x-y}. \tag{1}
$$
Combining the first two fractions we have
$$
\frac{d(x+y)}{y-x}=\frac{d\phi}{x-y} 
\implies d\phi=-d(x+y)
\implies \phi+x+y = C_1. \tag{2}
$$
In addition, we can rewrite the first equation in $(1)$ as
$$
(\phi-x)dx+(\phi-y)dy=0. \tag{3}
$$
Using $(2)$ to eliminate $\phi$ from Eq. $(3)$, we obtain
$$
(C_1-2x-y)dx+(C_1-x-2y)dy=0, \tag{4}
$$
which is an exact differential equation. Solving it, we obtain
$$
C_1(x+y)-x^2-xy-y^2=C_2, \tag{5}
$$
or, again using $(2)$ to eliminate $C_1$,
$$
(x+y)\phi+xy=C_2. \tag{6}
$$
The general solution to the PDE is, therefore, $C_2=F(C_1)$, or
$$
(x+y)\phi+xy=F(\phi+x+y), \tag{7}
$$
where $F(\cdot)$ is an arbitrary differentiable function.
Now, let's use the boundary conditions to determine $F(\cdot)$. The first one, $\phi=0$ if $xy=1$, implies
$$
1=F\!\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right). \tag{8}
$$
Since the image of $x\mapsto x+\frac{1}{x}$ is $(-\infty,-2]\cup[2,\infty)$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$, Eq. $(8)$ implies
$$
F(t)=1\quad\text{if} \quad t\in(-\infty,-2]\cup[2,\infty). \tag{9}
$$
The second condition, $x^2+y^2+\phi^2=a^2$ if $x+y+\phi=0$, implies
$x^2+y^2+(-x-y)^2=a^2$, or
$$
x^2+y^2+xy=\frac{a^2}{2}. \tag{10}
$$
Eq. $(7)$, on the other hand, implies
$$
F(0)=-(x+y)^2+xy=-x^2-y^2-xy. \tag{11}
$$
If follows from $(10)$ and $(11)$ that
$$
F(0)=-\frac{a^2}{2}. \tag{12}
$$
We conclude, therefore, that the solution to the problem is not unique: $\phi(x,y)$ is implicitly given by Eq. $(7)$, where $F(\cdot)$ is any differentiable function satisfying conditions $(9)$ and $(12)$.
